# What is ()=>{} in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was reading some Nodejs JavaScript examples and found something I have never seen before. What is `()=>{}` syntax? I tried googling it but not sure what keyword to put in.

```
  rl.on('line', (input) => {
    console.log(`Received: ${input}`);
  });
```

Comment: Generally referred to as an arrow function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: google  es6 arrow function ..

Comment: I'll be like https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&code=rl.on('line'%2C%20(input)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(%60Received%3A%20%24%7Binput%7D%60)%3B%0A%20%20%7D)%3B in es5

Comment: If you're planning to be a JavaScript programmer, you should quickly study up on what "ES6" features are. There are any number of good resources on the web about this; try googling "es6 new features".

Answer (score 2):

It's arrow function which comes in `ES6` to define function in new way.

Check the reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

**Example:**

```
let square = x => x * x;
let add = (a, b) => a + b;
let pi = () => 3.1415;

console.log(square(5));
console.log(add(3, 4));
console.log(pi());
```